# Swift 3 NSMutableParagraphStyle : NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping keep breaking the words

Tags: ios, swift3, fonts, nsmutablestring

I have a NSMutableParagraphStyle style that I apply to a NSMutableAttributedString:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let myString = "Before a telephone call, I need to go to the bathroom..."
        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
        let myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(
            string: myString,
            attributes: [
                NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(
                    name: "Georgia",
                    size: 45.0
                    )!,
                NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle
            ]
        )
        let textView = UITextView( frame: CGRect(
            x: 20,
            y: 25,
            width: 260,
            height: 400
        ) )
        textView.attributedText = myMutableString
        self.view.addSubview( textView )
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

But when I add that mutable string to a UITextView, it keeps breaking the words.

The word break does not appear at the same place when I go for `paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byCharWrapping`... So it does have an effect. But this is still partial. I have the word «call» that breaks after the «c», this is super weird.

[image: wtf]

And it is something I can reproduce in a storyboard editor :

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: for me your code works just fine as should, in an empty project using viewController.view as superview of your textView, so I think you problem is caused by other things I can provide as you can see here http://imgur.com/a/q5rjI

Comment: You are right, I misstyped some values. I edited to get you the full content of a test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aaaaaannnnddd the solution was to try editing my code in sublime text and realise that there is a non breakable space between telephone and call.

It seems a so stupidly basic functionality. Why can't Xcode tell me that...

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behaviour. As per Apple's documentation,

**byWordWrapping**

> Wrapping occurs at word boundaries, unless the word
>   itself doesn’t fit on a single line. See Characters and Grapheme
>   Clusters in String Programming Guide for a discussion of issues
>   related to determining word boundaries.

**byCharWrapping**

> Wrapping occurs before the first character that doesn’t fit.

For more information, please refer to [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslinebreakmode)

Comment: No it’s not. It says `Wrapping occurs at word boundaries`. There is no word boundary between the `c` and the `all` in the word `call`. And the word `call` fit in a single line.

Comment: With your initial post (without the screenshots), the question suggested that the word call was being displayed correctly with `byWordWrapping` and cut off with `byCharWrapping`. Hence my answer.
When it says `Wrapping occurs at word boundaries`, it means that if the whole word (determined by whitespaces) cannot fit on a line, it is moved to the next line

Comment: The blue screenshot was in my initial post. The word call is cut. The word telephone is not. If the space between call and telephone was not a non-break one (how did I managed to get one there...) it would clearly have been a bug in the platform. And in my opinion, we are not far from a bug. The fact that the UITextView is not smart enough to cut at the non break space if needed is disappointing. If I replace the space by an hyphen between call and telephone, the UITextView cuts at the hyphen. So it treats the hyphen as a potential whitespace. But not an actual space. Neat.

Comment: Disappointing, maybe (it's subjective). Bug, certainly not. You can probably add in a feature request to Apple for this (unfortunately, they don't have a separate feature request portal currently so you'll have to do it through the bug reporter)